# Espresso tests in android studio

Tags: android, android-espresso

it is possible to write a Espresso test in android studio outside the application's code ?
i read in the Espresso documentation that is possible to create a black-box tests with espresso but i dont find how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate project with the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

i Use this manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.test.test"xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.imc.imc" >
    <instrumentation>

 </manifest>
```

i create a new class in src/main/java/com.test.test named MainActivityTest

```
public class MainActivityTest {


    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<?> mActivityRule = newActivityTestRule("com.imc.imc.MainActivity");

    @NonNull
    private ActivityTestRule newActivityTestRule(String className) {
        return new ActivityTestRule(activityClass(className));
    }

    private static Class<? extends Activity> activityClass(String className) {
        try {
            return (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
private static int getId(String id) {
    Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    String packageName = targetContext.getPackageName();
    return targetContext.getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", packageName);
}

    @Test
    public void mytest() {
        onView(withId(getId("button"))).perform(click());;
    }


}
```

**but it does not work !!!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use UI Automator for cross-app functional UI testing,
for example, interacting with a GPS dialog box created using SettingsAPI.
Read more about it [here.](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/index.html)

[image]
Click the OK button like this :-

```
/** UI Automator Google GPS dialog box */
UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
UiObject uiObject = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("OK"));
try {
  uiObject.click();
}catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our [discussion thread at reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4asbao/is_it_possible_to_use_espresso_tests_against_apk/), there is one solution for this.

Also I am developing a plugin for Android Studio that will make this easy. You can [subscribe for news about it](http://droidtestlab.com/blackbox/index.html) and I will notify you when it will be ready.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, It is possible to write an Espresso test in the android studio outside the application's code.

All the test classes excluding instrumental test should be in the (test) folder as shown in the picture below

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efn4i.jpg)

Below is an example test class that checks whether the login is correct or not using the espresso test.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule
                = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testLoginSuccess() {

        onView(withId(R.id.et_username)).perform(typeText("testuser"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.et_password)).perform(typeText("test123"), closeSoftKeyboard());

        onView(withId(R.id.btn_login)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.tv_welcome)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }   
}
```

I wrote an explanation about it in my blog with a simple login example [here](http://codewithabdul.com/2019/10/02/android-automated-user-interface-testing-with-espresso/).

Comment: Please don't just add a link, but add some explanation yourself. You can improve the answer by adding some code, or explaining how it should be done, or by simple quoting from the link. More info here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259